# Simulate platform for Cordova plugin in production

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to use a Cordova plugin without using the native parts, only the browser implementation. In my case [cordova-plugin-googlemaps](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps). Is it possible to tell a plugin to use browser mode only?

If not, how could I edit the plugin?

Comment: use google map javascript API. and don't use this plugin as it is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

As Najam said, I suggest you to use JS Google Maps API for this purpose, but If you want to use it anyway you only have to make sure you haven't added any platform.

You can also modify your own implementation of the cordova-plugin-googlemaps, and add it to your project as a custom plugin, the steps are found here:

https://medium.com/@martinchuka/cordova-custom-plugin-easy-than-expected-with-ionic-wrapper-51d8c8bb082c

Hope it helps :D